# How to add row with value to existing datatable in console Application

Tags: c#, console

I have datatable on which I have to perform filter like where, order by. I have list of customerName. I want to filter data for each customername 
I tried below code for same

```
 foreach (string customer in CustName)
            {
 Datarow[] DataDR = TradeFinanceBF3.Select(TradeFinanceBF3.Columns["Cust_Name"].ColumnName.Trim() + "='A'", "USD equi DESC");
      }
```

I get datarow, then how to pass it to dataTable, and how to pass all customer data to same datatable.

I tried LinkQuery Also to filter data as below

```
      foreach (string customer in CustName)
            { 
 DataTable selectedTable = TradeFinanceBF3.AsEnumerable()
                          .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Cust_Name") == customer)
                          .OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<double>("IndexABC"))
                          .CopyToDataTable();

        ///Datable OutPut= ????? 

       }
```

I got datatable, But then how to add all customer data to one datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

`DataRow[] result = TradeFinanceBF3.Select("Cust_Name ='A'", "USD equi DESC");`

`DataTable aux = TradeFinanceBF3.Clone();`

```
        foreach (DataRow record in result)
        {
            aux.ImportRow(record);                
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But If I have list of customer name, then how will be my code? Is all data store in same data table

Comment: To filter and order a `List<string>` you might use  `CustName.OrderBy(b => b).Where(a => a.Contains('A')).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks...Its perfectly work for me. one more question...how to change background color of datatable

Comment: No, I want to create Excel sheet from datatable, then how to change background color of datatable

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will fix your issue

```
    [Test]
    public void GetCustomerData()
    {
        DataTable TradeFinanceBF3 = GetTable();
        DataTable NewDatatable = TradeFinanceBF3.Clone();
        IList<string> CustName = new List<string> { "Janet", "David" };
        var selectedTable = (from dataRow in TradeFinanceBF3.AsEnumerable()
            join customerName in CustName on dataRow.Field<string>("Cust_Name") equals customerName
            select new
            {
                CustName = dataRow["Cust_Name"],
                IndexABC = dataRow["IndexABC"]
            }).OrderByDescending(p=>p.IndexABC);
        foreach (var table in selectedTable)
        {
            NewDatatable.Rows.Add(table.CustName, table.IndexABC);
        }
        Console.Write(NewDatatable);
    }

    private DataTable GetTable()
    {
        // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Cust_Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("IndexABC", typeof(double));
        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add("David", 1);
        table.Rows.Add("Sam", 2);
        table.Rows.Add("Christoff",2);
        table.Rows.Add("Janet", 4);
        table.Rows.Add("Melanie", 6);
        return table;
    }
```

Comment: Hye thanks, it works, but I  custname get me below 1st column which name is another, I want it below column name Cust_name